# Python remove empty dictionary from nested json containing list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, recursion

i have a deep nested json file as shown below:

```
dict = [
{
"date":"2017-05-31",
"sections":[
 {
    "item":"BalanceSheetFormat2Heading",
    "value":"None",
    "sections":[
       {
          "item":"TotalAssets",
          "value":"None",
          "sections":[
             {
                "item":"FixedAssets",
                "value":"None",
                "sections":[
                   {
                      "item":"IntangibleAssets",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"PropertyPlantEquipment",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"InvestmentsFixedAssets",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[
                         {
                            "item":"LoansToGroupUndertakings",
                            "value":"None",
                            "sections":[

                            ]
                         },
                         {
                            "item":"OwnShares",
                            "value":"None",
                            "sections":[

                            ]
                         }
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"InvestmentProperty",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"BiologicalAssetsNon-current",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "item":"CurrentAssets",
                "value":"None",
                "sections":[
                   {
                      "item":"TotalInventories",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"BiologicalAssetsCurrent",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"Debtors",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[
                         {
                            "item":"PrepaymentsAccruedIncome",
                            "value":"None",
                            "sections":[

                            ]
                         },
                         {
                            "item":"DeferredTaxAssetDebtors",
                            "value":"None",
                            "sections":[

                            ]
                         }
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"CurrentAssetInvestments",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[
                         {
                            "item":"InvestmentsInGroupUndertakings",
                            "value":"None",
                            "sections":[

                            ]
                         },
                         {
                            "item":"OwnShares",
                            "value":"None",
                            "sections":[

                            ]
                         }
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"CashBankOnHand",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "item":"PrepaymentsAccruedIncome",
                "value":"None",
                "sections":[

                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "item":"TotalLiabilities",
          "value":"None",
          "sections":[
             {
                "item":"Equity",
                "value":9014904.0,
                "sections":[

                ]
             },
             {
                "item":"ProvisionsFor",
                "value":"None",
                "sections":[
                   {
                      "item":"RetirementBenefitObligationsSurplus",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "item":"Creditors",
                "value":"None",
                "sections":[
                   {
                      "item":"UseCurrentNon",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "item":"TradeCreditorsTradePayables",
                      "value":"None",
                      "sections":[

                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "item":"AccruedLiabilitiesNot",
                "value":"None",
                "sections":[

                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
]
}
]
```

what i want to achieve is removing the object that have an empty `sections` and `value` equal to `None`, the whole object should be removed from the dictionary  for instance

```
{
    "item":"IntangibleAssets",
     "value":"None",
      "sections":[]
                  
 }
```

The final output should looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "date":"2017-05-31",
    "sections":[
  {
    "item":"BalanceSheetFormat2Heading",
    "value":"None",
    "sections":[
       {
          "item":"TotalLiabilities",
          "value":"None",
          "sections":[
             {
                "item":"Equity",
                "value":9014904.0,
                "sections":[

                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
]
}
]
```

i have tried to check if an object is empty or not using this function:

```
def is_single_element(obj):
    # print(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if "item" in obj and "value" in obj and "sections" in obj:
            if obj["value"] == "None" and len(obj["sections"]) == 0:
                return True
    return False
```

and recursively walk the json and  remove those obj using:

```
def remove_single_obj(dict_):
    if isinstance(dict_, dict):
        for k, v in list(dict_.items()):
            if is_single_element(v):
                remove_single_obj(v)
    if isinstance(dict_, list):
        for index in range(len(dict_)):
            if is_single_element(dict_[index]):
                dict_.pop(index)
        remove_single_obj(dict_)
    return dict_
```

but i still cannot get the needed result.
Any help is much appreciated
Best

Comment: `if not is_single_element(v)` i think this is a typo? why `not`?

Comment: yup, i updated it but still cannot get the needed results

Comment: can you simplify the input, for example, you can reproduce the problem with at most 3 nested levels, and each list could just have 2 items, and the strings of item do not be that long since they are not related to the question. just make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: yes sure it's updated

Comment: the item names are still too long

Comment: please check now, it's updated  just now

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this looks suspicious:

```
for index in range(len(dict_)):
    if is_single_element(dict_[index]):
        dict_.pop(index)
```

Notice that `dict_` here isn't a dict, but a list... Then, let's say you have a list of 3 elements, [A, B, C], of which the first two should be removed. First you will remove item A, making the list [B, C]. Then the loop starts over with index 1, thus failing to ever look at item B! And finally, it looks at item 2, which is out of range!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code.
It assumes data root is a list, and are list items are dict, and all dict has 'sections' list, recursively. So no need check type via `isinstance`.

```py
def delete_emtpy_from_l(l):
    len0 = len(l)
    l[:] = [d for d in l if 'value' in d and d['value'] != 'None' or d['sections']]
    cnt = len0 - len(l)
    for d in l:
        cnt += delete_emtpy_from_l(d['sections'])
    # cnt is how many dict are deleted
    return cnt


# loop until no new dict is deleted
while delete_emtpy_from_l(data):
    pass

pprint(data)
```

output:

```
[{'date': '2017-05-31',
  'sections': [{'item': 'BalanceSheetFormat2Heading',
                'sections': [{'item': 'TotalLiabilities',
                              'sections': [{'item': 'Equity',
                                            'sections': [],
                                            'value': 9014904.0}],
                              'value': 'None'}],
                'value': 'None'}]}]
```